# For a HashMap that maps from a custom class, how to make it so that two equivalent keys will map to say value?

Tags: java

I have a custom class, for example's sake let's say it's tuples without order.

```
public class UnorderedTuple {  
    Integer i1 = null; Integer i2 = null;

    UnorderedTuple(Integer int1, Integer int2) { i1 = int1; i2 = int2; }

    boolean equals(UnorderedTuple t) { return t.i1 == i1 && t.i2 == t2 || t.i2 == i1 && t.i1 == i2; }
}
```

Like I said, a dumb example. Now, let's say i have

```
Map<UnorderedTuple, Integer> m = new HashMap<UnorderedTuple, Integer>();
```

Ideally, I'd like this functionality:

```
UnorderedTuple ut1 = new UnorderedTuple(1,2);
UnorderedTuple ut2 = new UnorderedTuple(2,1);

m.put(ut1,2);
m.put(ut2,3);
System.out.println(m.get(ut1)==3); //ideally returns true
```

Is there something I need to implement or extend such that I can have this functionality? In the same way that if you use 2 different, but equal strings, or Integers, or whatever as a key it will map it properly, but if I implement this as written, it treats ut1 and ut2 separately. Even if I construct ut1 and ut2 identically, it does the same thing.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to override `hashCode()`... in this case you'd probably do it by XORing the hash codes of all the fields involved, to get the order-independence you want.

You also need to override `equals(Object)` rather than just implementing `equals(UnorderedTuple)`.

I also note that you're using "==" to compare instances of `Integer`: don't do that. It will work in the test case you've given due to the rules around boxing, but if you try it with values over 127 you may well run into problems - it's only comparing *references* rather than *values*. Call `equals` to compare values properly.

Answer (score 4):

You need to implement [`hashCode()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) in a way that is consistent with [`equals()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) (in other words, if `a.equals(b)` returns `true`, then `a.hashCode() == b.hashCode()` must be `true` as well).

[Chapter 3 of Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/effectivejava/Chapter3.pdf) (free PDF!) has all the nitty-gritty details!

Edit: an you also need to make sure that you're actually implementing `equals(Object)`. In your sample code you only implement `equals(UnorderedTuple)`, which is not the same!

Answer (score 2):

Did you implement equals() and hashCode()? That could be the problem. Link to docs [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html)

Answer (score 1):

Implement [hashCode](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=28)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to define a custom hash function which would evaluate to the same value for both of the tuples. This however is a non-trivial as the hash function is important in determining the performance of the hashmap.